# JavaScript method not working in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a button that calls the `AllEntered()` javascript method when it      is clicked and as you can see in the final if/else, it should either got to `submission.html` or `admin.html` but instead of going to either of those it just reloads the current page that I am on. This is all inside a form by the way and its purpose is to check if all checkbox inputs are checked. Also the alert doesn't i put for loop-number doesn't generate either.

```
zbutton onclick="AllEntered()" class="myButton">Submit</button>
<script>
    function AllEntered()
    {
      var ids = {"freshSoph", "participate", "respect", "leave", "illegal", "alcohol", "typeName"};
      var loopNumber = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < ids.length - 1; i++)
        {
            if(document.getElementById(ids[i]).checked)
            {
                loopNumber++;
                alert(loopNumber.value);
                }
            }
            if(loopNumber = ids.length)
            {
                window.open("submission.html");
            }
            else
            {
                window.open("admin.html");
            }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: It appears that there is an error in your JavaScript with the way that you are declaring it.  Try instead: 'var ids = ["freshSoph", "participate", "respect", "leave", "illegal", "alcohol", "typeName"];'  Also you can press F12 if you are using Chrome to display the developer tools to see any errors and step through your script.

Comment: what is the meaning of after add Curly brackets { in there alert(loopNumber.value);

Comment: @SachithMW that was just to test if it was going into the if statement

Comment: It seems like you made an error in your javascript code. To debug javascript errors, you can press F12 in your browser and go into the console tab where you can see a list of errors. You might have to refresh the page to see this list. This procedure is the same in practically any browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE, Edge, etc). This can be very useful to debug javascript programs.

Answer (score 1):

Open your browser developer tools. Read the error message.

You have a typo. An array is created with `[]`, not `{}`.

(And of course it reloads the page, that is what clicking a submit button inside a form does).

Comment: Thanks it was just in the typo, took java and html a long while ago so im a little rusty, and the button was not type submit it was just a button with the content being submit(sorry should have been clearer)

Comment: @KyleHornacek — It doesn't have a type attribute. It is a submit button.

Answer (score -2):

In your form, below this button, add one more button as a hidden input of type submit like so:

```
<button hidden type="Submit">
```

Your problem could be caused by the fact that you are missing a submit type button.

When a form has no button of type Submit ( which on click will submit the form to its target or TO ITS SELF if no target is specified. This is what we call postback, as in posting back to your self ) it will use any buttons click as a submit event raiser.

By adding an actual submit button you remove this default behaviour, while also ensuring the user cant click on it, as the control is not active when its hidden.

Comment: Err. No. The default type of a button is `submit`. It has nothing to with the existence (or lack thereof) of any other buttons.

Comment: yes a button is submit by defaut. So when you want to press a button in a form, without submiting but instead you want to run your own function, then you must provide at least one button, explicicty set to type="Submit",otherwise you will trigger a post back